# 'Unset' Button background

Tags: android, button, drawable

I'm changing the background drawable for my buttons when they're clicked (as they trigger functions such as play/record). While playing/recording, the button glows (a different 9-patch is set as the background) and turns into a stop button. My problem is that currently I'm using:

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_normal);
```

to set the background back again afterwards. This works, but the normal behaviour when I use `setEnabled(false)` is lost. After a button has been used, and reset to normal, it retains the normal background (rather than the dimmed one) when disabled. The text still changes colour though. Is there a way of 'resetting' the background of the button to default, so that it retains its normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer from [this blog post](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) in the end. What you have to do is create an xml document with all the different button states, and assign that rather than just an image to the background.